# ASP.net gridview, autorefresh, txt as source and maintain scroll position

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, scrollbar, refresh

I want this gridview to emulate a console, the text file I have is a server console log.

**I want it to:**

*Refresh when the file changes.(thus the timer)

*Scroll bar position maintained when updated, unless at bottom.

*When scroll bar position is at the bottom,stay at the bottom after databind update.

**Current Problem:** On timer, databind() moves the scrollbar position back to the top, and with a refresh so often you can't even scroll down at all.

Here is my current code. Thank you for your help!

**asp.net**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TEST CONSOLE.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.TEST_CONSOLE" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >  
<head runat="server">
</head>  
<body>  
<form id="form1" runat="server">  
<div>  
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            </asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="30" ontick="Timer1_Tick"></asp:Timer>
            <div style="width: 100%; height: 400px; overflow: scroll">
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true">  
                </asp:GridView>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>  
</div>  
</form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

**c#**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;

namespace WebApplication1
{
public partial class TEST_CONSOLE : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    StreamReader objStreamReader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("TextFile.txt"));
    var arrText = new List<string>();
   // ' Loop through the file and add each line to the ArrayList  
    while( objStreamReader.Peek() >= 0){
        arrText.Add(objStreamReader.ReadLine());
    }

    //' Close the reader  
    objStreamReader.Close();

    //' Bind the results to the GridView  
    GridView1.DataSource = arrText;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.DataBind();


    }
}
}
```

Comment: Where is the question and Problem/Issue you are having?

Comment: Added Problem to post.

Comment: found answer here http://forums.asp.net/t/1220070.aspx?how+to+maintain+scroll+position+in+gridview+or+datagrid+during+postback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found most of answer here
http://forums.asp.net/t/1220070.aspx?how+to+maintain+scroll+position+in+gridview+or+datagrid+during+postback

using ajax and these two functions

```
    function Func() {//document.getElementById("hdnScrollTop").value
    document.getElementById("divScroll").scrollTop = document.getElementById("hdnScrollTop").value;
}
function Func2() {
    var s = document.getElementById("divScroll").scrollTop;

    document.getElementById('hdnScrollTop').value = s;
```